# Natural way of inducing sequence of subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, symmetric-groups

Consider the trace map $tr: M_{n \times n} ( \mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$. It is well-known that this satisfies the property:

$$tr(AB) = tr(BA)$$

This is equivalent to $tr(A_1 \cdots A_n) = tr(A_{\sigma(1)} \cdots A_{\sigma(n)})$ if and only if $\sigma = (1 \cdots n)^k$ for some $k$ (it is easy to mistakenly believe that it implies $\sigma$ can be arbitrary).

If we abstract the underlying algebra here, there is some sense in which the abelian structure of $C_2 \le S_2$ induces the subgroups $C_n \le S_n$ (specifically, $C_n = \langle (1...n) \rangle$, which I omit from now on) for all $n$. To expand on this, consider the tuple:

$$(1, ..., n)$$

We can consider partitioning this into two tuples in an order-preserving way:

$$(1, ..., m)(m+1,...,n)$$

We consider $C_2$ acting by rearranging these tuples to get:

$$(m+1, ..., n)(1, ..., m)$$

In this way, I am stating that $C_2$ may be considered to induce the permutation $$\tau = (m+1, ..., n, 1, ..., m) = (1, ..., n) \in S_n$$

In a similar way, it is possible to consider a subgroup $H \le S_m$ inducing subgroups $H_n \le S_n$ for each $n \ge m$ -- the span of all permutations generated by breaking down $(1, ..., n)$ into $m$ sub-tuples and considering the permutation corresponding to the action of $\tau \in H$ on these sub-tuples.

---

We will also describe a sort of dual operation to this. Let $H \le S_m$. Then, $H$ induces subgroups $H_n \le S_n$ for all $n \le m$ as follows. Given some $\sigma \in H$, let $i_1, ..., i_n \in \{1, ..., m\}$ be pairwise distinct. Then, I state that $\sigma$ induces the permutation:

$$ 1 \mapsto \min_j {\sigma(i_j)}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n \mapsto \max_j {\sigma(i_j)}$$

Let $H_n \le S_n$ be the span of all elements $\tau$ induced in this way.

---

**Definition**: The sequence $(G_k \le S_k)$ is *consistent* if, for every $k$, the subgroup of $S_n$ induced by $G_k$ (by the first operation if $n \ge k$, or its dual if $n \le k$) is contained in $G_n$.

**Question**: Is it possible to have a consistent sequence with $C_k < G_k < S_k$ (i.e. proper subgroup inclusions) for some $k$?

- $ \exists k : G_k \neq \{e\} \implies C_k \le G_k \forall k$
- $ \exists k \ge 3 : G_k = S_k \iff \forall k, G_k = S_k$
- $ \exists k \ge 4 : G_k = A_k \implies \forall k, G_k = S_k$

I will not write the proofs for these. None are difficult.

I have found three examples of consistent sequences:

1. $G_k = \{e\} \forall k$
2. $G_k = C_k \forall k$
3. $G_k = S_k \forall k$

By the first result I stated, there are none "in between" (1) and (2). It would be of great interest to me to find a sequence between (2) and (3).

More generally, it would be helpful to know about any results on the structure of groups $G$ where $\langle (1...n) \rangle \le G \le S_n$.

Comment: How is $H_n$ defined?

Comment: @coiso I will elaborate on the case $H = C_2 \le S_2$. It is a bit of a pain to formalise in general.

Comment: Well, even an informal description would be better than nothing.

Comment: I would absolutely *not* say that the subgroup $C_2$ of $S_2$ "induces" the subgroup $C_n$ of $S_n$ (even setting aside that there may be multiple copies of $C_n$ that are not given by cycles of length $n$; e.g., $(12)(345)$ gives a cyclic subgroup of order $6$ in $S_6$). You may argue it "suggests" the subgroup, but "induces" carries a connotation that I do not believe to be present here.

Comment: @coiso Well, it was not nothing. That is exactly why I included the discussion about $tr$. But thank you for the feedback that it was too elliptical.

Comment: I vote to close since no specific question has been asked. (It is mainly a small research proposal with some vague "what about this" in the end.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree that it is imprecise that I have only referred to isomorphism classes of groups, when different isomorphism classes will give different results. I will add a disclaimer to clarify this, although I think writing $\langle (1...n) \rangle$ would be excessive. I do not otherwise see the issue with my use of the term "induce".

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Does it not fall under the purview of the reference request tag I applied? If you believe it should be closed, I won't demur, but I am open to suggested improvements.

Comment: Improvement would be to actually ask one (if you have more then please create separate posts) of these "interesting questions" that you have mentioned in the last paragraph, and also specify what is *exactly* you want to prove or analyze.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I guess I phrased that ambiguously. I was still working on it before I wrote the comment. I have now added a question. It took me a lot of typing to lay out an additional definition I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proposition**

Every consistent sequence is of the form $G_k \equiv \{e\}, C_k$ or $S_k$.

**Proof** (sketch)

We prove that $(\exists n \ge 3: C_n \le G_n, \; C_n \neq G_n) \implies (G_3 = S_3) \implies (G_k = S_k \; \forall k)$.

Firstly, observe that if $e \neq \sigma \in G_n$, then $\sigma$ cannot have any fixed points. Otherwise, let $1 \in \{1,2,3\}$ be fixed under $\sigma$. Since $\sigma$ is not the identity, there must exist an induced permutation which interchanges $2,3$. (This is easy to see if one considers the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$.) In particular, if $\sigma$ were to have a fixed point, then we would have $(23) \in G_3 \implies G_3 = S_3$.

Hence, every $e \neq \sigma \in G_n$ must not have any fixed points i.e. every non-identity element of $G_n$ must be a derangement. Recall that $(1...n) \in G_n$. Note that for any $\sigma \in G_n$, the permutation

$$(1...n)^{1-\sigma(1)} \sigma \in G_n$$

has $1$ as a fixed point. Thus, $(1...n)^{1-\sigma(1)} \sigma = e$.

$$\implies \sigma = (1...n)^{\sigma(1)-1}$$

$$\implies \sigma \in \langle (1...n) \rangle$$

Therefore, the only group of derangements $C_n \le G_n \le S_n$ is $C_n$.

We conclude that $(\exists n \ge 3: C_n \le G_n, \; C_n \neq G_n) \implies G_k = S_k \; \forall k$. $\square$

---

I may as well add why this was interesting to me.

**Lemma**

$N \le G$ is normal if and only if $xy \in N \implies yx \in N$.

One can also show that:

**Lemma**
$$(xy \in N \implies yx \in N) \iff (\forall n : x_1 \cdots x_n \in N \implies x_{\sigma(1)} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)} \in N \text{ for } \sigma \in \langle (1...n) \rangle)$$

This gives a natural reason to define $(G_n)$ and the notion of consistency as above. The other two possible consistent sequences correspond to the cases given below:

**Proposition**

1. $G_n \equiv \{e\} \iff N $ is not normal
2. $G_n \equiv S_n \iff G / N$ is abelian

**Corollary**

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. Then, for every $n$, $\sigma \in S_n \setminus C_n$, $\exists x_1, ..., x_n \in G$ such that:

$$x_1 \cdots x_n = e \; \; \text{ but } \; \; x_{\sigma(1)} \cdots x_{\sigma(n)} \neq e$$

**Proof**

$G / \{e\}$ is not abelian. $\square$